# Android RecyclerView item get focused

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i have a news recyclerview that shows list of news.
on user change scrolled list, i want to get number of each item viewed.
for example, in list of rows, if user see item #9 , count++;

[something like this image. get count of visited item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvEvU.png)

Comment: didn't understand your question can you provide some more details

Comment: post your code and be specific regarding your question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add `addOnScrollListener` to recylcer view and get first visible or last visible at layout manager.

```
recycler.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);



        Log.d("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "onScrolled: "+layManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition());
    });
```

ok for you question I guess onBindViewHolder in RecyclerView.Adapter will be perfect

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder= (ViewHolder ) holder;

   Log.d("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "position "+position);
   count++; //for that position
}
```

and you can add your count at that positions item

Comment: what is layManager?

Comment: your layouManager for recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

You can get a position of last visible RecycleView item by calling `holder.getLayoutPosition()` in your custom adapter function `OnBindVewHolder(..)`

The actual position should be lastItemVisible +1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the views number for each news, you can do it in `onBindViewHolder` method of your RecyclerView's adapter. But you must pay attention that it may call several time for each news and you must count only in first call.

Comment: You can add `boolean` variable to your news class and set it `true` when user view the news and submit it to your server. Next time you can check this `boolean` and if it was `true` then ignore it. Also you must get each news view state for each user every time from your server to prevent counting it in next application run.